# Batch file to change screen resolution in windows 7

Tags: batch-file, screen-resolution

A colleague has a two line batch script to open excel when he logs in to his pc. He just doubleclicks it and has recently copied it to his startup folder so its automatic. i was wondering if i could have one to change the screen resolution when doubleclicked.

The reason for this is i regularly connect to an overhead projector, but my resoulution on it is wrong and i have to manually change the resoulution and then change it back when im done.
I am avoiding having to install anything, so if possible, any solution should be a self-contained file (it's a work laptop!)

i was thinking it may be two files needed, the first to change resolution to 1024 x 768 and anotherto return it to 1280 x 1024. All help is appreciated.

cheers

Answer (score 3):

[DisplayChanger II from 12noon.com](http://12noon.com/?page_id=641) works beautifully and is free for personal use.

[DisplayChanger](http://12noon.com/?page_id=641) is designed to be called via command line or batch script, and runs on 64-bit machines.  It can also generate editable config files specifically for multi-monitor (or projector) setups - you manually set the displays up how you want, "create" a config for it, then call that configuration up at any time.

Another popular option is the open-sourced [Qres utility](http://qres.sourceforge.net), but note that is 32-bit only and is less configurable.

Answer (score 1):

If Poweshell is an option then [Change Screen Resolution with Powershell](http://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/1854-change-screen-resolution-with-powershell) can help.